# Как решить проблемы в системе контроля доступа?

Tags: архитектура, авторизация, любой-язык

В своём API я использую подход `RBAC` - управление доступом на основе ролей. В моей системе у каждого пользователя есть набор ролей, а у каждой роли - набор разрешений. Структура БД организована по мотивам фреймворка [`Zizaco/entrust`](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust#user-relation-to-roles): есть таблицы `users`, `roles`, `permissions`, `role_user`, `permission_role`.

Такая структура позволяет мне определять может ли вызвать данный пользователь конкретный метод или нет. Моя проблема заключается в том, что мне нужно сделать возможным контролировать дополнительные условия, а не просто возможность вызова метода. Абстрактные примеры таких дополнительных условий: модератор может исключать из чата пользователей, но не администраторов; пользователь может редактировать только сообщения от своего имени. Как правильно реализовать такой функционал?

Важный момент: в моей системе роли могут динамически создаваться, и им можно динамически выдавать разрешения. Поэтому просто прописать в коде что-то вроде `if($user->type == 'moderator' && $userToKick->type != 'admin') $action->allow();` я не могу.

Comment: Либо заводите отдельные permissions для таких случаев, что бы они могли обозначать не только методы, но и действия, которые уже эти методы проверят в своем коде. Либо ввести понятие уровня доступа, что бы конкретное право обозначало не просто доступ к методу но и несло некое число, которое метод может интерпретировать по своему, например проверяя отдельные его биты

Comment: @Mike, а где должен хранится "уровень доступа"? В таблице `permission_role`, верно?

Comment: Да, в permission_role

Comment: но с ним обычно такая проблема, что приходиться задавать например цифрами. если нет единого стандарта вроде чтение-запись-выполнение и каждый метод интерпретирует по своему то в пользовательском интерфейсе будет довольно сложно отобразить что то внятное.